# how to skip Numbers in Sql Server using Order by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

I have sql query which returns the following Result :

```
select * from Emp Order By EmpName asc
```

Result :

```
Empid  EmpName
1          1
2          2
3          3
A          ALL
N          NOTALL
```

but I want output like below :

```
Empid  EmpName
A          ALL
N          NOTALL
1          1
2          2
3          3
```

how can I achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a custom sort order either like this:

```
select * 
from Emp 
Order By 
    CASE WHEN IsNumeric(EmpName) = 1 then 0 else 1 end asc,
    Empid
```

or by adding an explict `SortOrder` column to the table

> [**Note**: ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not
>   numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such
>   as the dollar sign ($). For a complete list of currency symbols, see
>   Using Monetary Data.]

Comment: it's giving Error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'. btw both columns are varchar datatype..

Comment: problem with this solution is that 10 will order before than 2 in the ordering. But since QA has not described exactly what is needed, I guess  this will be sufficient. This answer is doing exactly what was requested

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: As you mention the answer is doing exactly what was requested, but I've updated to be less fragile. Thanks for noticing the flaw :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom sorting logic in your ordering something like:

```
ORDER BY
CASE 
WHEN EMPID = 'A' THEN 1
WHEN EMPID = 'N' THEN 2
ELSE CAST(EMPID AS INT) + 2
END
```

You could also use the `ISNUMERIC` function as described in Mitch Wheat's answer to avoid explicitly declaring the cases. However, in case you have a non-alphabetical order e.g. 'G' should appear before 'A', then it would be good to explicitly specify the values.